# Why does my app have different names on different devices?

Tags: java, android

The name of my app is Webmex, on some phones (including mine) shows it correct, but on other phones, it shows the name "GiraffePlayer".

[Correct name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbMhn.jpg)

[Wrong name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMIcu.jpg)

Of course I checked the name of the app in the manifest and the string value, and everything was correct.

[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbST2.png)

[String value of app name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzHqG.png)

I used the library GiraffePlayer to play videos on my app, and I don't know why my app is taking that name on some devices.

So far I've tested my app on 4 devices, and 2 of them had wrong the name.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Go to Manifest of library GiraffePlayer and then change label !

Comment: It's the launcher activity label that is more relevant than application label. But note that the "wrong" name is in a device with different locale, so likely your app_name is not translated the same way in all locales.

Comment: Thanks laalto! It was a problem with a translation to spanish.